# how to call a function assuming I have only .h file and .o file?

Tags: c, pointers, header

**Can I call a function assuming I have only .h file and .o file in C ?**

I mean if I only have `example.h` file and `example.o` file, but I don not have the `example.c` file and I want to read the function from a main file.

I know I can do that with pointers, but I don't really know how to do it. Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include<object.h>` to include the header and supply the path to the object file while compiling.

```
gcc main.c object.o -o main
```

Now you should be able to use the function.

Comment: Most likely `#include "object.h"`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, for the sake of those who are not familiar with C, `#include <file.h>` is used for library headers, whereas `#include "file.h"` is used for local files, i.e. those in the same project/folder/etc as the include directive.